# Prompt user to select device (from line)

Tags: android, batch-file, windows-10, adb

I'm trying to list the connected adb devices and prompt the user to select a line to deploy an APK to.

So far I've tried:

```
for %%i in (adb devices) do (
    ECHO %%i
)
```

But that won't work at all. Is there any way to capture the id of each adb device into variables? My goal if possible is to capture each id like:

```
%line1=f2ea3410
```

From adb listing *adb devices*:

```
f2ea3410        device
f2fa3410        device
```

So I can prompt the user the **line** (and not the id which is painful to type):

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p id="Enter Line:"
```

Comment: Which version of `MS-DOS` are you using?

Comment: @Compo standard dos prompt from windows 10

Comment: There hasn't been a version of DOS included with Windows, for more years than I can now remember!

Comment: @Compo how would you name the DOS prompt?

Comment: There isn't one, `cmd.exe` often uses the term `Command prompt`.

Comment: You can use the `FOR` command with the `/F` option to capture the output of a command.

Comment: @Squashman thanks leading me to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this with the example you provided. Just modify `:DoIt` to do whatever it is you want to do with the available Id.

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@rem @set prompt=$G

@set _command=adb.cmd
@set _count=0

@for /f "tokens=1,*" %%G in ('%_command% devices') do @call :AddAndDisplayDevice %%G "%%H"
@set /p _choice=Enter number from above menu:
@if not defined _%_choice% @goto :BadSelection "%_choice%"
@call :DoIt %_choice%
@exit /b 0

:AddAndDisplayDevice
@set /a _count+=1
@echo %_count%. %*
@call :SetVar %_count% %1
@call :SetVar %_count%_description %2
@exit /b 0

:BadSelection
@rem Up to you whether to loop back and try again.
@echo Bad choice: %_choice%
@exit /b -1

:DoIt
@set _Id=!_%1!
@rem set _
@echo User selected %1, device Id %_Id%.
@exit /b 0

:SetVar
@set _%1=%2
@exit /b 0
```

Adb.cmd, for testing:

```
@echo f2ea3410        device
@echo f2fa3410        device
```